# void ** handles with P/Invoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using a C API DLL from a 3rd party vendor.  The problem I have is that I can't seem to find a good template for Marshalling the following C code:

```
API_Open( void ** handle );
API_Close( void * handle );
```

The calls are simplified, but the handle is a void *, which is (in C) passed into the `API_Open` call as &handle, and then passed into `API_Close` as handle.

I've tried to do the same in C#, but can't figure out how to Marshal handle properly.  My C# version (latest try) is:

```
[DllImport("External.dll",EntryPoint="API_Open")]
public static extern int API_Open( out IntPtr handle );
[DllImport("External.dll",EntryPoint="API_Close")]
public static extern int API_Close( IntPtr handle );

public static int Wrapper_API_Open( ref Int32 handle )
{
    int rc = SUCCESS;

    // Get a 32bit region to act as our void**
    IntPtr voidptrptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Int32));

    // Call our function.  
    rc = API_Open(out voidptrptr);

    // In theory, the value that voidptrptr points to should be the 
    // RAM address of our handle.
    handle = Marshal.ReadInt32( Marshal.ReadIntPtr(voidptrptr) );

    return rc;
}

public static int Wrapper_API_Close(ref Int32 handle)
{
    int rc = SUCCESS;

    // Get a 32bit region to act as our void *
    IntPtr voidptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Int32));

    // Write the handle into it.
    Marshal.WriteInt32(voidptr,handle);

    // Call our function.
    rc = API_Close(voidptr);

    return rc;
}


public void SomeRandomDrivingFunction()
{
    .
    .
    .
    Int32 handle;
    Wrapper_API_Open( ref handle );
    .
    .
    .
    Wrapper_API_Close( ref handle );
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The API return code is always INVALID_DEVICE_OBJECT when I call API_Close.  Any thoughts?  I thought this would be pretty straightforward, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the void** and void* parts of the function calls.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you should just do `IntPtr handle; API_Open(out handle);` then later `API_Close(handle);`.

Comment: Just delete the Marshal.AllocHGlobal() hokey-pokey, the IntPtr is the handle.  Improve your error checking, throw an exception when API_Open() returns an error code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be over-complicating this significantly. I don't know why you want to introduce `Int32` for the handles since they do need to be pointer sized. You should use `IntPtr`.

The `API_Open` accepts the address of the variable where the handle is returned. The caller allocates that variable and passes it to the callee, which populates the variable. The C function might look like this:

```
int API_Open(void **handle)
{
    *handle = InternalCreateHandle();
    return CODE_SUCCESS;
}
```

You'd call that in C like this:

```
void *handle;
int retval = API_Open(&handle);
if (retval != CODE_SUCCESS)
    // handle error
// go one and use handle
```

Translated to C#, the `void*` maps to `IntPtr`, and the use of the double pointer is just a means to get around the fact that C only supports pass-by-value. In C# you would use pass-by-reference.

For `API_Close` it is even simpler because we are passing the handle by value:

```
int API_Close(void *handle)
{
    InternalCloseHandle(handle);
    return CODE_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the calling code is simply:

```
int retval = API_Close(handle);
if (retval != CODE_SUCCESS)
    // handle error
```

So, the C# wrapper functions should be:

```
public static int Wrapper_API_Open(out IntPtr handle)
{
    return API_Open(out handle);
}

public static int Wrapper_API_Close(IntPtr handle)
{
    return API_Close(handle);
}
```

At which point these wrapper methods do look somewhat pointless!

Comment: Ahh, the elegant simplicity of it all -- explains why I couldn't find any examples at any rate.  Thanks.